Configuration space of points on the REAL line
Can anyone kindly provide me with some intro or reference to the configuration space of $n$ points on the real line? The configuration space of $n$ points in $R^d$ is embedded in
$(R^d)^n \times (S^{d-1})^{\binom{n}{2}}\times [0,\infty]^{\binom{n}{3}}$ as described in  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610236. However, for $d=1$ the space is disconnected and $S^{d-1}$'s are points. So the description seems to change. Thank you.

$S^0={\pm 1}$, so the definition 2.11 still works with the usual definition of configuration space.
